# .net Maui Picker endlessly scrolls and repeats list of items

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I have a picker binded to a list of items - when the list fits the screen, there is no need for scrolling and it the list loads and operates well.  When the list gets over 10 items, there is a scrolling feature and the scroll on the tablet endlessly scrolls without stopping.  If you have a mouse attached to the tablet - you can activate it by the arrows on the picker and that causes the picker to behave as expected but not when you use the scroll wheel or finger on tablet mode.

```
<Picker x:Name="ListP"
    WidthRequest="450" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding List}" 
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Label}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWorkNoti}"
    TextColor="{DynamicResource QuatenaryTextColor}"
    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Gray400}">
```

Is there a Maui or Xaml setting to disable the endless scrolling to behave like a scroll bar to end when it reaches the bottom? Sample video

Comment: I'd open a bug on the MAUI repo

Comment: Is this on an emulator? Is the target Windows, or a mobile OS?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it’s a Windows.

Comment: I created a new project to test the picker but I can't reproduce your problem.